# buildah seems can't handle `npm install` writing file "`/sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control`: Operation not supported"

Tags: npm, buildah

## Situation

I get following error when I try to build a container image with buildah.

```sh
[1/2] STEP 7/8: RUN npm install
error running container: error from crun creating container for [/bin/sh -c npm install]: writing file `/sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control`: Operation not supported
```

## Environment/steps

1. I have installed `buildah` in an ubuntu container image called `tools-image`
2. I run this `tools-image` container on a macOS
3. I use docker to run the `tool-image` container
4. I start the `tools-image` container with

```sh
docker run -it --privileged --name demo -v "$(pwd)":/localmachine
    "myname/myname:v1" /bin/bash
```

5. I use inside the `tools-image` `buildah` to build an `example application` container image

```sh
buildah bud -t test:v1 -f Dockerfile .
```

## Dockerfile for the `example application` container image  I use with `buildah bud` command

This is the `Dockerfile`.

```
##############################
#           BUILD
##############################
FROM docker.io/node:17-alpine as BUILD 
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY public /usr/src/app/public
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY babel.config.js /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

##############################
#           EXAMPLE
##############################
# https://blog.openshift.com/deploy-vuejs-applications-on-openshift/
FROM docker.io/nginx:1.21.4-alpine

RUN apk update \
    apk upgrade \
    apk add --update coreutils

# Add a user how will have the rights to change the files in code
RUN addgroup -g 1500 nginxusers 
RUN adduser --disabled-password -u 1501 nginxuser nginxusers 

# Configure ngnix server
COPY nginx-os4-webapp.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
WORKDIR /code
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/app/dist .

# https://zingzai.medium.com/externalise-and-configure-frontend-environment-variables-on-kubernetes-e8e798285b3e
# Configure web-app for environment variable usage
WORKDIR /
COPY docker_entrypoint.sh .
COPY generate_env-config.sh .
RUN chown nginxuser:nginxusers docker_entrypoint.sh
RUN chown nginxuser:nginxusers generate_env-config.sh
RUN chmod 777 docker_entrypoint.sh generate_env-config.sh
RUN chown -R nginxuser:nginxusers /code
RUN chown -R nginxuser:nginxusers /etc/nginx
RUN chown -R nginxuser:nginxusers /tmp
RUN chmod 777 /code
RUN chmod 777 /tmp
RUN chmod 777 /etc/nginx

USER nginxuser

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/bin/sh","docker_entrypoint.sh"]
```

## Error when I execute

```sh
[1/2] STEP 1/8: FROM docker.io/node:12-alpine AS BUILD
[1/2] STEP 2/8: COPY src /usr/src/app/src
--> d6601e0d631
[1/2] STEP 3/8: COPY public /usr/src/app/public
--> febd88b92b3
[1/2] STEP 4/8: COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
--> 26675130145
[1/2] STEP 5/8: COPY babel.config.js /usr/src/app/
--> 1006f1e8cf3
[1/2] STEP 6/8: WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
--> af1b28ef62c
[1/2] STEP 7/8: RUN npm install
error running container: error from crun creating container for [/bin/sh -c npm install]: writing file `/sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control`: Operation not supported
: exit status 1
[2/2] STEP 1/22: FROM docker.io/nginx:1.21.4-alpine
Trying to pull docker.io/library/nginx:1.21.4-alpine...
error building at STEP "RUN npm install": error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with podman!

## Steps which solved the problem for me:

1. I installed `podman` on macOS
2. I builded the `tools-image` with `podman`
3. I started the `tools-image` with following command

```sh
podman run -it --rm  --privileged --name demo "tools-image:v1"
```

4. I cloned the code for the `example application` into the `tools-image` running container
5. I ran `buildah` with following command

```sh
buildah bud -t test:v1 -f Dockerfile .
```

## Result

It worked with podman!

```sh
[2/2] COMMIT test:v1
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 1a058d5342cc [--------------] 0.0b / 0.0b
Copying blob ad93babfd60c [--------------] 0.0b / 0.0b
Copying blob 5af959103b90 [--------------] 0.0b / 0.0b
Copying blob 385374b911f2 [--------------] 0.0b / 0.0b
Copying blob eabae5075c43 [--------------] 0.0b / 0.0b
Copying blob 3d71b657b020 [--------------] 0.0b / 0.0b
Copying blob 57627a47445a done  
Copying config 204e250881 [========] 10.6KiB / 10.6KiB
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
--> 204e250881d
Successfully tagged localhost/test:v1
204e250881d44984be77c4abfef100880bda165b3d195606880fcad026b57003
```